# How do I print rows of a CSV file that have a specific keyword in them?

Tags: python, csv

My current code only print out the exact input that matches the line in the CSV file.

```
import csv
import sys

#input name you want to search
name = input('Enter name to find\n')

#read csv, and split on "," the line
csv_file = csv.reader(open('test.csv', "r"), delimiter=",")


#loop through the csv list
for row in csv_file:
    #if current rows 2nd value is equal to input, print that row
    if (name == row[0]):
        print (row)
    elif (name == row[1]):
         print (row)
```

Comment: It's not really clear what exactly about this code isn't doing what you want, but you should just `print(row)` if you want to print the whole row.

Comment: I want to print out all lines that includes "london" as the csv have london paddingdon, london king cross, etc.

Comment: You could do something like `if name in row[0].split()`. That will split the first column of the row into a list of words and if `name` is in that list it will pass the test and print the row.

Comment: @ber can you provide the data inside the csv file

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import sys

#input name you want to search
name = input('Enter name to find\n')

#read csv, and split on "," the line
csv_file = csv.reader(open('railway_stations.csv', "r"), delimiter=",")

#def error():
#    print("error")

#loop through the csv list
for row in csv_file:
    #if current rows 2nd value is equal to input, print that row
    if (name in row[0].split()):
        print (row[1])
    if (name in row[0].split()):
         print (row[0])
```